# How can I check if a value implements an interface dynamically?

Tags: go, reflection

Assuming I have an interface called `Hello` like:

```golang
type Hello interface {
   Hi() string
}
```

I want to write a function that gets `Hello` and any interface `n` and does something if `Hello` also implements `n` interface, like:

```golang
type Person interface {
  Name() int
}

type Animal interface {
  Leg() int
}

type hello struct{}

func (h hello) Hi() string {
    return "hello!"
}

func (h hello) Leg() int {
    return 4
}

func worker() {
   h := hello{}

  // Doesn't match
  check(h,(Person)(nil))

  // Matches
  check(h,(Animal)(nil))
}

func check(h Hello, n interface{}) {
  // of course this doesn't work, should I use reflection, if so how?
  if _,ok := h.(n); ok {
      // do something 
  }
}
```

How to implement the `check` function?

Answer (score 8):

Use reflection [`Type.Implements`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Type)

```
func check(n interface{}) bool {
    i := reflect.TypeOf(new(Hello)).Elem()
    return reflect.TypeOf(n).Implements(i)
}
```

If the interface you want to use as reference is known, you can just instantiate it with `new(Hello)` or `(*Hello)(nil)` without passing an extra argument to the function.

You can't use `(Hello)(nil)` [because](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#TypeOf):

> If i is a nil interface **value**, `TypeOf` returns `nil`.

Otherwise if the reference interface is also dynamic, you can pass it as an argument. The principle is the same:

```
func main() {
     fmt.Println(check(new(Hello), new(Person))) // false
}

func check(i interface{}, n interface{}) bool {
    ti := reflect.TypeOf(i).Elem()
    return reflect.TypeOf(n).Implements(ti)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/GYDcxtIobKc

---

After generics will be added to the language in Go 1.18 (early 2022), you will be able to write a generic function for this that uses a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

> If `T` is an interface type, `x.(T)` asserts that the dynamic type of `x` implements the interface `T`.

It would look like:

```
func check[T any](i T, n interface{}) bool {
        _, ok := n.(T)
        return ok
}
```

Go2 Playground: https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/HIBn3IYW13W

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use reflection for this.

```golang
func check(h Hello, n interface{}) {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(n).Elem()
    if reflect.TypeOf(h).Implements(rt) {
        fmt.Printf("%T implements %s\n", h, rt)
    }
}

func worker(s Hello) {
    //...
    check(s, (*Person)(nil))
    //...
}
```

Note that you need to use `(*Person)(nil)`, `(Person)(nil)` will not work.

https://play.golang.org/p/2Bhy49SSol9