# How to test if a generic type can fit a more restrictive interface - golang

Tags: go, generics, data-structures, type-conversion

I am building an all-purpose data structure, that I intend to use in various contexts and with various bits of data.

I am currently attempting to make a matcher, that will look into my structure and return all nodes containing the data given. My problem being that, since I need my structure to be as generic as possible, I **need** my data to be of a generic type matching `any`, and this won't allow me to make equalities.

I have built a "descendant type" (there's probably a correct term, I'm self-taught on this) that has the more rigorous `comparable` constraint.

I want to see if I can convert from the more general one to the more specific one (even if I have to catch an error and return it to the user). I know that I don't *specifically* need to, but it makes the code understandable down the line if i do it like that.

Here's a bit of code to explain my question :

```golang
type DataStructureGeneralCase[T any] struct {
    /*
       my data structure, which is too long to make for a good example, so I'm using a slice instead
    */
    data []T
}

type DataStructureSpecific[T comparable] DataStructureGeneralCase[T]

// this works because any contains comparable

func (ds *DataStructureSpecific[T]) GetMatching(content T) int {
    /*The real function returns my custom Node type, but let's be brief*/
    for idx, item := range ds.data {
        if item == content {
            return idx
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func (dg *DataStructureGeneralCase[T]) TryMatching(content T) (int, error) {
    if ds, ok := (*dg).(DataStructureGeneral); ok {
        // Does not work because dg is not interface, which I understand
    } else {
        return -1, fmt.Errorf("Could not convert because of non-comparable content")
    }
}
```

My question can be summarized to "How can I do my conversion ?".

Comment: The example here has too many compiler errors to try and guess what you are actually trying to do. Can you make a [mre]? You don't have any conversions in the source here, but the only way to conditionally have a conversion is using reflection since types are all defined at compile time (not to mention there aren't really any generics at runtime, they must each be instantiated already).

Comment: @JimB I have done a bit better, unfortunately, I can not solve all compilation errors since I do not know how to do ```ds, ok := (*dg).(DataStructureGeneral); ok``` in a way that does not return one. You can forgo reading the functions, I just want to be able to convert from the general case type to the specific one

Comment: What you have is a type assertion, not a conversion. What is `DataStructureGeneral` supposed to be? Maybe just put a real type conversion in there without any conditions and seeing what the error is will help clarify things. I think you're going to run into "cannot use ... without instantiation" errors, because there are no generics at runtime.

Comment: Maybe you don't really want a plain "type conversion",  are you looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587996/cannot-use-type-assertion-on-type-parameter or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68497744/how-can-i-check-if-a-value-implements-an-interface-dynamically?

Comment: So I have to go into my structure, which is in reality a graph, and convert every value one by one ? That seems very slow

Comment: Nope, it's ok, I finally understood, you have to wait until the types are declared. I attemtped this, but since I'm working with pointers half the time, I confused myself

Comment: An alternative to using 'any' is to define your own aliases for all non-local types you would like to use (e.g., `type MyInt int`). You can then use your own interface since you can define all methods of that interface for your aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func CheckImplements[T any, I any]() bool {
    var o T
    _, ok := interface{}(&o).(I)
    return ok
}
```

So yeah, runtime only.

Comment: mind the language

Comment: @ray [It's against policy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233) Ah, well frick frack frick frick!

Comment: better to be found by me than found by mods lol

Comment: go has a lot of advantages, but yes i agree that sometimes it is quite innconvenient

Comment: @AlexSHP Well I don't regret choosing Go for this project because it meets the right parameters. I do regret my design based upon the assumption that it would be a more "reasonable" language. Had I understood sooner, the core of my software would be in C++ and the "easy to customize extensions" would be in Go with only a small amount of the "glue" in between in Go.

Comment: @AlexSHP Don't get me wrong, I'm still glad they've added generics, but I'm used to the power of C++ template metaprogramming and this doesn't even come close. The problem (in my view) is that their implementation must satisfy language requirements that a larger audience (of less intellectually gifted persons) can use it and not get themselves in lost in deeply complex problems, which is possible to do with a real, meta-programming-capable implementation. But this means we can never have powerful mechanisms, like full classes.

Answer (score 0):

Cast to the empty interface first:

```
castedDg := interface{}(dg)
if ds, ok := castedDg.(DataStructureGeneralCase[T]); ok {
```

They explain why they chose this approach in https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#why-not-permit-type-assertions-on-values-whose-type-is-a-type-parameter

Comment: Instead of ```interface{}``` I prefer ```any```, there is a difference when you cast structs.

Comment: @MandeepGill `any` is an alias to `interface{}`, and as such, they are completely equivalent and interchangeable.

Comment: @MandeepGill  `any` is an alias for `interface{}` added in go 1.18.   Many code samples, and modules pre-date 1.18, and often modules use `interface{}` for compatibility.